# Streaming API Twitter - Get the public Stram

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

I'm using the hbc tools to build an app using streaming Api. I just want to get the public streaming flow without any trackword or others filters.
How can I manage to do that?
Here is a sample of code I wrote:

```
StatusesFilterEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("#aTweet"));
Authentication auth = new OAuth1(consumerKey, consumerSecret, token, secret);
Client client = new ClientBuilder()
            .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .authentication(auth)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(queue))
            .build();
// Establish a connection
client.connect();
```

With this, I can just track a tweet but not all the public flow of tweet.
Thanks for your answers ^^

Answer (score 0):

StatusesFilterEndpoint uses [filter](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) endpoint and it returns just matched tweets. There is also StatusesSampleEndpoint implementation in hbc-core which returns small random sample from all tweets.